# GeoDjango, distance between two points

Tags: python, django, geo, geodjango

I have the following model:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=200)
    coordinates = models.PointField(null=False, blank=False)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I'm trying to find a distance between two cities above using the following:

```
city1=City.objects.get(name='New York')
city2=City.objects.get(name='Boston')
city1.coordinates.distance(city2)
```

But getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/home/rok/apps/django-trunk/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 667, in distance
    raise TypeError('distance() works only on other GEOS Geometries.')
TypeError: distance() works only on other GEOS Geometries.
```

Looking at structures and data, it seems to be ok:

```
>>> city1.coordinates.coords
(40.714623,-74.006605)
>>> city2.coordinates.coords
(42.360024, -71.060168)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess there should be `city1.coordinates.distance(city2.coordinates)` instead of `city1.coordinates.distance(city2)`

Comment: You are right, such an obvious one that I missed after starring at the code for half an hour... thanks!

Comment: @zero323 I cannot get GeoDjango running. Can you please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507033/how-to-access-a-geometry-point-field-in-postgis-database-from-django)?