# How to access a geometry (point) field in PostGIS database from Django?

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

In my project I am using PostgreSQL/PostGIS as the database and Django with [`django.contrib.gis`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/) configured. The **existing table** `pois` contains geospatial **point** data. Here is a excerpt from the SQL create statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pois
(
  ogc_fid serial NOT NULL,
  the_geom geometry(Point,900914),
  name character varying(254),
  -- ...
```

I generated the Django model with the following command:

```bash
$ python manage.py inspectdb
```

The generated model looks like this:

```python
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class POIs(models.Model):
    ogc_fid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    the_geom = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) # This field type is a guess.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pois'
```

I add the following field to overwrite the default manage with a GeoDjango specific instance:

```python
objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Now, I want to replace `the_geom = models.TextField()` with the **correct data type** which should be either [`models.PointField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield) or [`models.GeometryField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geometryfield). I tried both. Then I test the model at the Python shell:

```bash
$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jul 28 2015, 18:20:59) 
In [1]: from berlin import models
In [2]: models.POIs.objects.first()
```

This fails and the following **stacktrace** is output:

```
/home/user/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/ \
    gis/db/models/fields.py in select_format(self, compiler, sql, params)
     57         else:
     58             sel_fmt = '%s'
---> 59         if connection.ops.select:
     60             # This allows operations to be done on fields in the SELECT,
     61             # overriding their values -- used by the Oracle and MySQL

AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'select'
```

There is **no error** when I leave the model with `models.TextField`. Then the string value is output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database configuration in *settings.py* was incorrect:

```python
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'geodjango',
        'USER': 'geo',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Correct:

```python
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', # Here
        'NAME': 'geodjango',
        'USER': 'geo',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I have overseen this in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#configure-settings-py) somehow. Thanks to *apollo13* from the `#django` irc channel for the advice into the right direction.